# spring security passwordencoder

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

So this is my first code

```
@Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
        registry.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

I wanted to use password encoder so i turn my code to this

```
@Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
            ShaPasswordEncoder sha= new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
        registry.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(sha);
    }
```

but its still not working.. what seems to be the problem with this code? im pretty new to java config.. I hope someone can help me out..

Comment: What are the @Autowired annotations doing there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Silly me... The problem is not Spring security. My sha-256 generation in register is not correct. That's the reason why i can't login.. This is my code now.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(user.getPassword().getBytes());

byte byteData[] = md.digest();

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
            .substring(1));
}
user.setPassword(sb.toString());
```